# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a game using HTML5, but because I'm new to programming I have many errors that I don't understand. `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` is one of them. I dont use jQuery, i use dom to add/remove classes

How can I fix the below code so it no longer gives that error?

```
   var dom = start.dom,
    $ = dom.$,
    canvas, ctx,
    pUruchomienie = true;


function createBackground() {
    var background = document.createElement("canvas"),
        bgctx = background.getContext("2d");

    dom.addClass(background, "background");
    background.width = 640;
    background.height = 480;

    bgctx.fillStyle = "rgba(225,235,255,0.15)";
    for (var x=0;x<10;x++) {
        for (var y=0;y<10;y++) {
            if ((x+y) % 2) {
                bgctx.fillRect(
                    x * 2, y * 2,
                    2, 2
                );
            }
        }
    }
    dom.addClass(background, "board-bg");
    return background;
}


function setup(){
    var boardElement = $("#ekran-gry .ekran-planszy")[0];
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    dom.dodKlase(canvas, "plansza");
    canvas.width = 640;
    canvas.height = 480;
   // boardElement.appendChild(createBackground()); <- is where error pop up
    boardElement.appendChild(canvas);              <-  is where error pop up
```

CSS code & HTML

```
    #ekran-gry .ekran-planszy {
    position : relative;
width : 640px;
height : 480px;
 }

#ekran-gry .ekran-planszy .board-bg,
#ekran-gry .ekran-planszy .plansza {
position : absolute;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}


  </div>
        <div class = "ekran" id = "ekran-gry">
            <div class = "ekran-planszy"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is a jsfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ukjh45Lr/

Comment: $("#ekran-gry .ekran-planszy")[0] probalby doesn't return any value. You can check that in a debugger.

Comment: Well, apparently, `boardElement` is undefined. Have you checked that you really have an element with ID `ekran-gry` that contains an element with class `ekran-planszy`? Do you use jQuery? Because there is a weird line at the beginning that could cause it to fail : `$ = dom.$`

Comment: Use `append` instead of `appendChild`.

Comment: error fixed, needed to change class name in my css file. Thanks 4 help